# Call PHP file every 5 seconds

Tags: php

I have a call to a page which I call as follows:-

`include_once('status.controller.php');`

I want to call this function every 5 seconds, so it re-runs the scripts without refreshing the whole page.

How can I do this?

I've tried:-

```
var interval = 4800;

setInterval(function() {
    $.get('status.controller.php', function(data) {
      //do something with the data
      alert('Load was performed.');
    });
}, interval);
```

but it doesn't appear to be re-running the scripts on the page as it is not updating the session variables as it should be.

Comment: Use Javascript `setInterval` and an AJAX request.

Comment: [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)). I'm sure a simple Google search could've found that for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153750/calling-a-php-function-every-second?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

```
        $("document").ready(function() {
          window.setInterval(function(){
          $.ajax({
            url: 'status.controller.php.php',
            success: function(data) {
            }
          });
        }, 5000);
```

This will work for you, just include jQuery js files, if you hadnt.

Source : [What's the easiest way to call a function every 5 seconds in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170923/whats-the-easiest-way-to-call-a-function-every-5-seconds-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(function(){
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'status.controller.php',
        success:function(data){
            if(data == "status.controller.php"){
            }else{
                alert(data);
                location.reload();
        }
        }
    });
},4000);
});
</script>
```

I think this is your questions respond.