# Laravel 5 Scheduled Command everySeconds?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a scheduled command as such:

```
public function schedule(Schedulable $scheduler)
{
    return $scheduler->everyMinutes(1);
}
```

Is there a way to get this to run every ten seconds?

Comment: No you can't Cron only allows for a minimum of one minute. otherwise you have to write some shell scripts with infinite loop. Bad Idea.

Comment: You can not do it. Cron has a 60 seconds granularity.

Comment: What about having five identical scripts but each has a sleep() of 10 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the scheduler in laravel is based on the cron format.

So you can not define a repetition smaller than minutes. You might use a workaround : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619362/running-a-cron-every-30-seconds)

Answer (score -1):

What you are thinking off is something called long-polling and it does not scale good on PHP especially when you use blocking IO.

Something like this:

```
set_timeout_limit(11);
$i=0;
while ($i<10) {
    i = i + 1;
    sleep(1); // sleep 1 second
}
```

[Calling A PHP Function Every Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11153750/calling-a-php-function-every-second)

Also:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6488569/11926